# JPA2 Criteria and Java 8 Date&Time API

Tags: datetime, java-8, jpa-2.1

I try to port a Java web application to the new Java 8 Date&Time API (using 'LocalDate' and 'LocalDateTime' types among others)

In Java 7, java.util.Date could be used in JPA2 criteria API to filter result sets on dates. Typically one would do this by adding a predicate e.g.

```
..
predicatesList.add(builder.between(from.get(AccountLog_.valueDate), fromDate, toDate));
..
```

Now JPA2 doesn't support the new Java 8 Date&Time API (LocalDate and LocalDateTime) yet. With own "Attribute Converters", working with entities can already be achieved as described in the blog http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/persist-localdate-localdatetime-jpa/

Now to my question: how can I use LocalDate and LocalDateTime in JPA2 criteria API in order to filter the result sets on **LocalDate** instead of Date? 'between' as used previously doesn't work for LocalDate instances.

Comment: JPA2.2 fix this or not?

Comment: @Krismorte according to [https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/whats-new-in-jpa-2-2/](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/whats-new-in-jpa-2-2/) you seem to be right. Though did not try it out yet

Comment: I'm face this problem too here is my question 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48585691/problems-with-between-localdate-predicate

Answer (score 7):

With my `LocalDateTimeConverter`, I just tried `greaterThanOrEqualTo` and `lessThan` to check for a `LocalDateTime` range like

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Meal> query = cb.createQuery(Meal.class);
Root<Meal> m = query.from(Meal.class);
query.select(m);
query.where(
    cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo(m.<LocalDateTime> get(Meal.FIELD_WHEN), cb.literal(begin)),
    cb.lessThan(m.<LocalDateTime> get(Meal.FIELD_WHEN), cb.literal(end))
    );

return em.createQuery(query).getResultList();
```

and even

```
cb.between(m.<LocalDateTime> get(Meal.FIELD_WHEN), cb.literal(begin), cb.literal(end))
```

works as expected. What exactly is causing trouble with your code? Maybe `<LocalDateTime>` is missing?