# JPA 2.1: Introducing Java 8 Date/Time API

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, eclipselink, jpa-2.1

**I'd like to add support** for the **Java 8 Date/Time API (JSR-310)** in my JPA-enabled application.

It's clear that **JPA 2.1** [does not support the Java 8 Date/Time API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23718471/324152).
As a workaround, the most common advise is to use an [`AttributeConverter`](http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/persist-localdate-localdatetime-jpa/).

In my existing application, I changed my entities to use `LocalDate`/`LocalDateTime` types for the column mapping fields and added legacy setter/getters for `java.util.Date` to them.
I created corresponding `AttributeConverter` classes.

**My application does now fail** when using `Query.setParameter()` with `java.util.Date` instances (it worked before the transition to the new API). 
It seems that JPA expects the new date types and does not convert it on the fly.
**I expected that if passing an argument** to `setParameter()` of a type for which an `AttributeConverter` has been registered, it **would be automatically converted** by the converter.
But this seems to be not the case, at least not using `EclipseLink 2.6.2`:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You have attempted to set a value of type class java.util.Date for parameter closeDate with expected type of class java.time.LocalDate from query string SELECT obj FROM [...]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.setParameterInternal(QueryImpl.java:937) ~[eclipselink-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2.v20151217-774c696]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.setParameter(EJBQueryImpl.java:593) ~[eclipselink-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2.v20151217-774c696]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.setParameter(EJBQueryImpl.java:1) ~[eclipselink-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2.v20151217-774c696]
  [...]
```

***Questions***:

1. Is this behavior **expected**? Did I miss something?
2. Is there a **way** to use the new date types as fields **without breaking existing code**?
3. **How did you deal** with the transition to the new Date/Time API within JPA?

***UPDATE:*** 
However, It seems that at least using EclipseLink, custom types for which an `AttributeConverter` exists, are not fully supported:
Within JPQL queries, **neither the actual field type nor the converted database type can be used as a parameter**.
When using the converted database type, the exception described above occurs.
When using the actual field type (e.g. `LocalDate`), it's directly passed to the jdbc driver which doesn't know this type:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObjectCritical(OraclePreparedStatement.java:10495) 
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObjectInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:9974) 
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObjectInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:10799) 
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObject(OraclePreparedStatement.java:10776) 
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.setObject(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabasePlatform.setParameterValueInDatabaseCall(DatabasePlatform.java:2506)
```

I would expect that EclipseLink converts the field type to the java.sql type using the AttributeConverter.
(see also this bug report: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=494999 )

Which leads us to the most important question #4:

4. Is there a workaround/solution to support java 8 date fields using `EclipseLink`, **including the possibility to use a query parameters on such a field**?

**ADDITIONAL INFO**

- [AttributeConverter used (for LocalDateTime conversion)](http://pastebin.com/yMfM2jXF)
- [Additional information to reproduce exception](http://pastebin.com/9p9AT8Rc)

Comment: I don't know JPA, but why use, say, java.util.Date instead of java.sql.Date? The sql* types have been retrofitted to convert from/to JSR 310 types

Comment: I believe for now you need to add another dependency to get Java 8 support in Hibernate. The removes the need for you to specify AttributeConverters around Data/Time classes. See:http://stackoverflow.com/a/37098160/1356423

Comment: What's your code for the converter and the actual query with parameter?

Comment: @SteffenHarbich I've updated the question, now providing converted code and query

Comment: MRalwasser, there are differences to [my entity and converter implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37628540/1063673). You could try to change your code according to mine, to test whether it makes any difference. My converter uses Timestamp as DB data type and the @Temporal annotation is not required.

Comment: @SteffenHarbich This pushed me one step further - thank you. It seems that the target type of the `AttributeConverter` needs to be a `java.sql` type (despite the fact that `java.util.Date` works perfectly as an entity field). Simple queries do now work. However, when using the same parameter more than once within a query, EclipseLink seems to not convert the value after the first occurrence, resulting in the exception described above. Adjusting your query to `"SELECT p FROM MeasuringPoint p WHERE p.when = :custDate AND p.when = :custDate"` should reproduce this.

Comment: I tried it and works as expected, no error. Did you change the parameter value from Date to LocalDateTime? Maybe post your code.

Comment: @SteffenHarbich Can you try the query `SELECT p FROM MeasuringPoint p WHERE p.when = :custDate AND p.when -1 = :custDate`?

Comment: What is the intention of "-1" in the query? I would guess it is not valid JPQL.

Comment: It should substract a day from p.when before comparing it to the parameter. But the -1 does not really matter. Any JPQL which uses :custDate for another time (in a different expression as the first usage) should reproduce the exception.

Comment: Strange. At least there is the work-around of using another parameter name with the same value for the second occurrence.

Comment: The -1 in the query brings up a syntax exception when I execute it.

Answer (score 4):

Some time ago, I converted a Java EE 7 web app from Java 7 to Java 8, and replaced `java.util.Date` in entities with `LocalDate` and `LocalDateTime`.

1. Yes, that behavior is expected, because an `AttributeConverter` only converts between the type used for entity fields and the *database type* (ie, `java.sql.Date`, etc.); it does not convert between an entity field type and a `java.util.Date` used in a query parameter.
2. As far as I know, no, there is no way to continue using `java.util.Date` in existing code, after introducing the `java.time` types into JPA entities.
3. Besides creating the necessary `AttributeConverter` implementations, I changed all occurrences of `java.util.Date` to the appropriate `java.time` types, not only in entities but also in JPA-QL queries and in business methods.

For item 2, of course you can go some way by using utility methods and getters/setters that convert between `java.util` and `java.time`, but it's not going to go *all* the way. More importantly, I don't quite see the point of introducing `java.time` types into JPA entity attributes, if you are not willing to convert the remaining code that uses these 
attributes. After the conversion work I did in that Java EE app, there were no uses of `java.util.Date` left anywhere (though I also had to create converters for JSF).

Comment: Regarding 1: I've updated the question, citing the JPA 2.1 spec.

Comment: I'm talking about a fairly large code base. I wish I could yet migrate to the new API all at once. Unfortunately, budget and time does not allow this for now. I'd like to support the new API in the entities which would encourage our team to use it for future tasks and during refactoring of existing code. At some break-even point, we'll do the complete transition.

Comment: JDBC drivers only understand `java.sql` types, not `java.util.Date`. So, the JPA converters are only between `java.time` and `java.sql` types (at least in my case, they were); they won't convert a `java.time.LocalDate` to a `java.util.Date` and then to a `java.sql.Date` (which in turn gets mapped to a native database `DATE` type).

Comment: l don't think JDBC plays a role in my question at all. We're using java.util.Date fields in our JPA entities since many years, EclipseLink cares about talking to the JDBC driver (and a conversion to java.sql.Date). My question is just about AttributeConverter, (expected) conversion within JPQL and alternatives to my approach.

Comment: Regarding 2: At least when using eclipselink, using the java.time types as query parameters will fail, too (see also https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=494999 ). So I can  neither use the java.util.Date nor the new types as query parameters. How did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

With so many bugs in the provider itself I don't think you have much choice but to use `java.util.Date` on the mapping level and java 8 dates on the API level.

Assuming you write a utility class for [conversion to/from `java.util` dates](http://blog.progs.be/542/date-to-java-time) called `DateUtils`, you could define your mappings as follows:

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {

  @Column("DATE")
  private Date date; // java.util.Date

  public void setDate(LocalDateTime date) {
    this.date = DateUtils.convertToDate(date);
  }

  public LocalDateTime getDate() {
    return DateUtils.convertFromDate(date);
  }
}
```

Then to filter by `date` in JPQL:

```
public List<MyEntity> readByDateGreaterThan(LocalDateTime date) {
  Query query = em.createQuery("select e from MyEntity e where e.date > :date");
  query.setParameter("date", DateTuils.convertToDate(date));
  return query.getResultList();
}
```

So, `java.util` dates would be used in entities and DAOs (Repositories) internally, while the API exposed by entities and DAOs would take/return java 8 dates, thus enabling the rest of the application to operate with java 8 dates only.

Comment: That's more or less what we're doing today. One drawback with that way is that the JPQL Parameters need to be converted to `java.util` types beforehand.

Answer (score 2):

I have the following setup:

- EclipseLink v2.6.2
- h2 Database v1.4.191
- Java 8

The entity class is like:

```
@Entity
public class MeasuringPoint extends BaseEntity {

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime when;

    public void setWhen(LocalDateTime when) {
        this.when = when;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getWhen() {
        return when;
    }

}
```

The required converter for JPA 2.1 is:

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class LocalDateTimeConverter implements AttributeConverter<LocalDateTime, Timestamp> {

    @Override
    public Timestamp convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalDateTime attribute) {
        return attribute == null ? null : Timestamp.valueOf(attribute);
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDateTime convertToEntityAttribute(Timestamp dbData) {
        return dbData == null ? null : dbData.toLocalDateTime();
    }

}
```

Now I can make a query

```
List<?> result = em.createQuery(
         "SELECT p FROM MeasuringPoint p WHERE p.when = :custDate")
         .setParameter("custDate", LocalDateTime.now())
         .getResultList();
```

and it works like a charm. The result contains the expected entities. The conversion to TIMESTAMP is done automatically. When you have queries using the Criteria API, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35101366/jpa2-criteria-and-java-8-datetime-api/37236181#37236181) which shows how to use `LocalDateTime` within Criteria API queries.

I wonder why it doesn't work with your code. Maybe the H2 JDBC driver does support something your Oracle doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

AttributeConverter is working as designed, as the converter is meant to handle the back and forth between your entity type and the database type.  Validation is verifying the type of the parameter doesn't match the type within the entity - just because your attribute converter can handle it, doesn't mean it fits the contract of the attribute converter types.  JPA only says it will go through the converter before going to the database, and in this case it doesn't go to the database.

If you don't like Rogério's suggestions, you can 
1) modify the EclipseLink code to relax the validation to allow it to go through to your converter, or 
2) change your attribute type to 'Object' instead so that all parameter types you may pass in will go to your converter.