# Problems with between LocalDate Predicate

Tags: java, java-8, predicate

This is my table

[image]

The selected column is the one that I'm using in Predicate

My first approach was

```
  public void betweenPredicate(String attrib, LocalDate value, LocalDate value2) {
        Predicate predicate = builder.between(entity.<LocalDate> get(attrib), builder.literal(value), builder.literal(value2));                
        predList.add(predicate);
    }
```

But in that way some date are missing, so I change to this

```
 public void betweenPredicate(String attrib, LocalDate value, LocalDate value2) {
        Predicate predicate = builder.and(builder.<LocalDate>greaterThan(entity.get(attrib), value),
                builder.<LocalDate>lessThan(entity.get(attrib), value2));
        predList.add(predicate);
    }
```

In that way works perfeclty, so my question is What is the main different betweent this two way, Am I done something wrong?

**EDIT**

This is my screen I'm using `netbeans 8.2` with `DatePicker` from `swingx 1.6`

[image]

DatePicker send me Date, but my class receive LocalDate so a have this Convert Method

```
public static LocalDate dateToLocalDate(Date data) {
        if (data != null) {
            return data.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

and I added two println at `betweenPredicate` to see how the values are getting there
and this is the output

```
V: 2018-02-01
V2: 2018-02-16
```

Comment: In SQL `between` both values are included. In your 2nd case they are excluded

Comment: @SergeyLagutin I know this and in SQL works fine, but in Java some data between the values are missing and I don't know why.

Comment: but we don't see it from your question.

Comment: @SergeyLagutin I put more information

Comment: add some unit tests to check if your db layer is correct. mb issue is with other fields